# QOpenGLWidget fullscreen toggle

Tags: c++, windows, qt, opengl, qt5

I am using Qt 5.6 on Windows (built with the opengl desktop flag, no ANGLE) and I have a widget inheriting QOpenGLWidget as follows:

```
class SomeWidget: public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
    ...
}
```

This widget is added in a layout in the main window and has the main window as a parent. The OpenGL stuff displays fine. I want to maximize or make fullscreen that widget and then restore it back to its position / size in the main window. The code looks like that:

```
onFullscreen()
{
    // remove widget from layout
    // set widget's parent to NULL
    // create a new dialog / layout and add widget to it
    // call dialog->showFullScreen
}

onRestore()
{
    // set parent to main window
    // insert in main window layout
    // restore original size
    // close dialog
}
```

I also added in main():

```
app.setAttribute(Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts); // onFullscreen() crashes if this line is not present
```

I get a black screen when I go to fullscreen and don't see the red clear color. There is no error message.

Interestingly if I replace dialog->showFullScreen() by dialog->showMaximized() the original rendering disappears and I don't see another dialog.

I have the same approach to display another widget fullscreen that does not derive QOpenGLWidget and it works fine.

Any idea on what is going on and how I could achieve to display the QOpenGLWidget in fullscreen and restore it back in its place in the main window ?

Many thanks !

Comment: Why not to show your main window in fullscreen mode ( and expanding the widget to cover it in full ) ?

Comment: Thanks c-smile for the feedback. How would you expand the widget to cover in full ? I was thinking that the other solution is better because if I create another dialog I can still have access to the controls when I have a second monitor.

Comment: I have very strong feeling that you cannot "reparent" OpenGL widgets that easy. OpenGL is bound with the window context it was created on. I suspect that creating another OpenGL window and re-render stuff there will be the easiest thing to do.

Comment: @c-smile: OpenGL contexts are *not* tied to the window they were created with. Unfortunately Qt (and many other) frameworks don't expose that very well. It's near impossible to use this feature with Qt-4 and with Qt-5 it's not trivial. But one can definitely use a single OpenGL context with several different windows.